# If M is recognizing L in polynomial time, is it also deciding it in polynomial time?

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity, decision-problem, polynomial-time

> Assume that a given turing machine $M$ accepts words in the language
>   in $n^k$ or less steps, but words that aren't in the language
>   are rejected in unknown number of steps (the machine might even loop).
>
> $k$ is unknown.
>
> Is $L(M)\in P$?

Well, obviously $L(M)$ is recognized in polynomial time. The question is whether it's possible to decide $L(M)$ in polynomial time.

It seems to me that the answer is no, but I can't figure a way to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible. Simulate $M$ for $n^k$ steps. If it has accepted so far, accept. Otherwise, reject. You can simulate $M$ for $n^k$ steps in polynomial time (perhaps $O(n^{2k})$), hence this is a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: k is unknown, we just know that such a k exists. But I can't figure how to find it.

Comment: This is absolutely not a problem. You are not required to construct an algorithm that converts $M$ into a polynomial time decider, you only need to show that if a polynomial time recognizer exists, then a polynomial time decider exists.